# Simple Function Errors when Running in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am very new to program and VBA. I am trying to play around with VBA in Access so I wrote this little thing to test my understanding. However, when I git run, it pops up empty Macro dialog/window instead of a Message box says the things in the code ( I thought it would). Could anyone take 5 secs to let me know what did I miss please. Thank you very much

```
Public Function AddOne(value As Integer) As Integer
AddOne = value + 1
End Function
MsgBox "Adding 1 to 5 gives:" & AddOne(5)
```

Comment: Is Value in your msgbox a variable that has an actual value assigned somewhere?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, the last line should be       & AddOne(5)

Comment: You should watch this series:[Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's not possible to `Run` a macro that takes any arguments/parameters from the "Run" dialog.**

So if you press <kbd>Run</kbd> button, or <kbd>F5</kbd>, you'll see the Dialog box because that is Excel asking you "Which procedure do you want to run".

[image]

It will display any available procedures. Procedures which take any argument(s) will not be visible, since the arguments would not be supplied.

**A few other points:**

Your `MsgBox` statement is outside of the function. It should be inside the function

```
Function AddOne(val As Integer)
    Dim ret As Integer
    ret = val + 1
    'Display msgBox:
    MsgBox "Adding 1 to " & val & " gives:" & ret
    'return to caller:
    AddOne = ret
End Function
```

**Since you can't run from the dialog, you need to invoke this manually from the `Immediate` window:**

[image]

Or, you can simply print the result to immediate window using the following in the Immediate pane:

```
?AddOne(5)
```

Which will print "6" in the Immmediate.

[image]

Comment: He might not want the MsgBox every time the Function runs, so I'd suggest a separate Sub for the MsgBox just for simplicity sake.

Comment: @Chrismas007 I don't care and that's not relevant to the problem, but thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanks Chris and David